# Converted WSDL to WCF Web Service. WCF WSDL does not match original WSDL

Tags: asp.net, wcf, web-services, wsdl

I have converted a WSDL to a WCF web service. However, when I run the WCF service and check the WSDL, it does not match the WSDL originally used to create the service. Why?

The original WSDL (CORERule2.2.0.wsdl) and XSD (CORERule2.2.0.xsd) files used to create the WCF web service can be found [here](http://www.caqh.org/SOAP/WSDL/).

Answer (score 1):

The WSDL you get from your web service is automatically generated by WCF. You can find a concise explanation about it in the following post: [WCF Metadata](http://www.danrigsby.com/blog/index.php/2008/05/27/wcf-metadata/).

If you didn't change anything in the web service, the generated WSDL should contain the same contract as the one from the original WSDL.

And if you really need to provide the same WSDL back to your clients, then you could supply an external WSDL by using the ExternalMetadataLocation property on the ServiceMetadataBehavior.